# How to get data by using join in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a table:

[image]

and this table:

[image]

I would like to create report like this

[image]

I've tried this SQL:

```
select
    master_problem.problem,
    master_problem.sop_reference,
    master_problem.adidas_spec,
    count(log_roving_qc.id_problem) as jumlahfrom
master_problem
inner join log_roving_qc
    on master_problem.id_problem = log_roving_qc.id_problem
group by master_problem.id_problem
```

but the empty data does not show. I want to display blank data with a description of 0

Comment: I have attempted to fix the problems with the query you actually showed us.  If you want something other than this, then edit your question and make that more clear.

Comment: Chang inner join to left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a left join of the `master_problem` table to a subquery which does the count aggregation:

```
SELECT
    mp.problem,
    mp.sop_reference,
    mp.adidas_spec,
    COALESCE(t.cnt, 0) AS jumlahfrom
FROM master_problem mp
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id_problem, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM log_roving_qc
    GROUP BY id_problem
) t
    ON mp.id_problem = t.id_problem;
```